# creating a link to pdf files in netbeans

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans

I am working on a project in netbeans, and right now I want to embed links to various pdf files so that when that link is clicked, the program will call up the appropriate pdf in it or somewhere in the hard disk and open it with the pdf viewer.

I came across a 'clickable label' concept in one article, but I dont know how to do that, all the labels I insert do not link to the source tab when I double click on them.

Can someone please provide an example of how to implement a 'clickable label'?

Comment: What type of application are you building?  Android App, Desktop Application, Website?

Comment: I'm not a Java Developer, but I did a quick Bing search and found this: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-java/

Comment: OK. It is a Desktop Application. Thanks for the link too

Comment: thanks alot, mr J. that link did the magic...